# Pastes HTML formatted text into into outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, html, copy-paste

I have an html email (email.html) formatted and ready to go. How can I paste the html code (Using Outlook 2007) into a new message and keep the html formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open it in IE and press <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

The next step is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: The next step is to paste the clipboard content into the new message. :-) It messes up a little of the formatting but this is less steps than what I was doing. Thanks!